# How to reset dropdown to zero index in MVC?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

in my mvc project i bind a dropdown like below in a div

```
@{
    List<SelectListItem> lsqty = new List<SelectListItem>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
         SelectListItem sl = new SelectListItem { Text = i.ToString(), Value = i.ToString(), Selected = false };
         lsqty.Add(sl);
    }
}
Qty: @Html.DropDownList("ddlQty", lsqty, new { style = "width:30px", @class = "positive-integer" })
```

that from a html list like below

```
<select style="width:30px" name="ddlQty" id="ddlQty" class="positive-integer">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

on some buttom i do some functinality, so i want to reset this Dropdown to zero index, how can i do that?

Comment: Do you mean that you want `0` value in the options ?

Comment: yes the ddl reset, start from index 0.

Comment: Did any answer helped you ? If yes pls accept the helpful answer..

Answer (score 1):

If you binding the dropdown through code then in the button click event set the

```
DropDownList.SelectedIndex = 0 ;
```

or if you are binding it statically the simply use the method

```
DropDownList.ClearSelection();
```

Try this :

```
document.getElementById("<%#mydropdownlist.ClientID%>").value = 0;
```

or

```
document.getElementById("<%#mydropdownlist.ClientID%>").selectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: i used this in the ajax function but it doesn't work.
document.getElementById("<%#mydropdownlist.ClientID%>").selectedIndex = 0;

Comment: use this [link](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1161649) its may be helpful for you.

Comment: @Sandy the code you have provided is not application in MVC applications Since there is not any `ClientID` and `DropDownList` or `Controls` concept it is purely HTML snippets, Helper Functions, and JavaScripts..

Answer (score 1):

[Live JsFiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/7EBxV/)

I think you want the values to start from `0` value so you have to change the for loop a bit and rest I think you can get from the [JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/7EBxV/) to change the selected index

**Logic**

```
@{
    List<SelectListItem> lsqty = new List<SelectListItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) // Starting loop from ZERO *******
    {
         SelectListItem sl = new SelectListItem { Text = i.ToString(), Value = i.ToString(), Selected = false };
         lsqty.Add(sl);
    }
}
Qty: @Html.DropDownList("ddlQty", lsqty, new { style = "width:50px", @class = "positive-integer" })
```

**And the output should be**

```
<select style="width:50px" name="ddlQty" id="ddlQty" class="positive-integer">
  <option value="0">0</option> //New Option value ZERO
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

And the Javascript for selected index would be

```
document.getElementById("ddlQty").selectedIndex = 0;
```

*PS: Since you are building ASP.NET MVC application* `<%#mydropdownlist.ClientID%>` *syntax is not applicable, instead directly use the `id` that you have in the **logic** section.*

> @Html.DropDownList("ddlQty"... <--- This is the **ID**